# Python-Kafka: Keep polling topic infinitely

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-python, kafka-topic

I am using python-kafka to listen to a kafka topic and use that the records. I want to keep it polling infinitely without any exit. This is my code below:

```
def test():
    consumer = KafkaConsumer('abc', 'localhost:9092', auto_offset_reset='earliest')
    for msg in consumer:
        print(msg.value)
```

This code just reads the data and exits directly. Is there a way to keep listening to topics even if message is not pushed to it?

Any relevant example where the topic is continuously monitored is also great for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Using [`confluent_kafka`](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python)**

```
import time
from confluent_kafka import Consumer


consumer = Consumer({
    'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9092',
    'group.id': 'my-consumer-1',
    'auto.offset.reset': 'earliest'
})
consumer.subscribe(['topicName'])

while True:
    try: 
        message = consumer.poll(10.0)

        if not message:
            time.sleep(120) # Sleep for 2 minutes

        if message.error():
            print(f"Consumer error: {message.error()}")
            continue

        print(f"Received message: {message.value().decode('utf-8')}")
    except:
        # Handle any exception here
        ...
    finally:
        consumer.close()
        print("Goodbye")
```

---

**Using [`kafka-python`](https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python)**

```
import time
from kafka import KafkaConsumer

consumer = KafkaConsumer(
     bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'],
     auto_offset_reset='earliest',
     group_id='my-consumer-1',
)
consumer.subscribe(['topicName'])

while True:
    try: 
        message = consumer.poll(10.0)

        if not message:
            time.sleep(120) # Sleep for 2 minutes

        if message.error():
            print(f"Consumer error: {message.error()}")
            continue

        print(f"Received message: {message.value().decode('utf-8')}")
    except:
        # Handle any exception here
        ...
    finally:
        consumer.close()
        print("Goodbye")
```

Comment: can you please why we need to do `consume.poll` here? what does that 10 mean?

Comment: @mifol68042 It's the timeout: https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/KafkaConsumer.html#kafka.KafkaConsumer.poll

Comment: does the message returned from `consumer.poll` when using `kafka-python` have `error()` or `value()`? I got an `AttributeError - 'dict' object has no attribute 'value'` exception when calling `message.value() or message.error()`. I use kafka-python 2.0.2 and `KafkaConsumer.poll()` returns dictionary as a response.

Comment: same thing, poll result doesn't have value() or error()

Answer (score 4):

for kafka-python following solution worked

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer


    def consume_message(topic_name):
        consumer = KafkaConsumer(
            bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'], auto_offset_reset='earliest'
        )
        consumer.subscribe(topic_name)
        while True:
            try:
                records = consumer.poll(timeout_ms=1000)
    
                for topic_data, consumer_records in records.items():
                    for consumer_record in consumer_records:
                        print("Received message: " + str(consumer_record.value.decode('utf-8')))
                continue
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                continue
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative option is to use [`aiokafka`](https://aiokafka.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html), a client built upon `kafka-python` that provides coroutine-based analogues; since this keeps the `asyncio` event loop hydrated with tasks, it's possible to run a coroutine using the high-level `asyncio.run()` API that polls a topic and stays alive until the program is terminated:

```py
import asyncio
import logging
import os
from aiokafka import AIOKafkaConsumer

consumer_group_id = os.environ["APPLICATION_CONSUMER_GROUP_ID"]
logger = logging.getLogger(consumer_group_id)

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, force=True)

async def consume():
    consumer = AIOKafkaConsumer(
        os.environ["APPLICATION_CONSUMER_KAFKA_TOPIC"],
        group_id=consumer_group_id,
        bootstrap_servers=["kafka:29092"],
        value_deserializer=
    )

    await consumer.start()

    try:
        async for message in consumer:
            logger.info(message.value)
    finally:
        await consumer.stop()


asyncio.run(consume())
```